# How can I get a list of all properties in a mixin in Polmyer 2.x?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a mixin and a class that uses it, but within the mixin (or the class itself), I can't seem to get a list of all properties. `this.config` is `undefined`, and `this.constructor.config` only gives me the list of properties in the current class (not those in the mixin itself).

See below for a more detailed example.

```
const myMixin = subclass => class extends subclass {

    static get config() {
        return {
            properties: {
                mixInVariable: {
                    type: String,
                }
            }   
        }
    }   

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.constructor.config.properties);
    }

}

class ContainerGrid extends myMixin(Polymer.Element) {

    static get is() { return 'container-grid' }

    static get config() {
        // properties, observers meta data
        return {
            properties: {
                something: {
                    type: String
                }
            }
        };
    }

}

customElements.define(ContainerGrid.is, ContainerGrid);
```

In the console, I only see the variable `something`. How can I get a list of all properties (e.g. `mixInVariable` and `something`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `constructor`, use `super.constructor.config.properties` to access the inherited properties.

```
class XFoo extends MyMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  ...

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('constructor(): ', super.constructor.config.properties);
  }
}
```

From `get properties()`, use `super.config.properties`.

```
class XFoo extends MyMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  ...

  static get properties() {
    console.log('get properties(): ', super.config.properties);
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ENrGWy?editors=1010)

Comment: thx that worked as a workaround... but actually I wanted to access all the properties in the mixin itself. I guess that's not possible with "plain" ES6 but would need some Polymer function?

Comment: The example I've shown provides access to all the mixin's properties. Try the codepen. The properties must be accessed from the child element that extends the mixin, and not from the mixin itself. There is currently no Polymer function that would allow a mixin function to access a collection of all properties from both the mixin and child.

Comment: I'm unable to get the codepen working. I'm not sure exactly how Polymer 2 has changed since the preview release that renders this example not working.

Comment: @JuniperBelmont I've updated the example to work with Polymer 2.0 release.